# Change the order of the boxes when the window's size is reduced in html, css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I was wondering if it's possible to change the order of the boxes when the window's size is reduce. For now, I have this:

[Big window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlSNx.png)

And when I reduce the window's size I got this:

[Small window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VKOa.png)

but what I want is one under the other like this:

1

3

2

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Looks as though you want to employ breakpoints in your CSS. Check out this MDN docs page for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media

Essentially, you set width characteristics and style accordingly. This is essentially as close as CSS comes to being a logical programming language (aside from animations).

Playing with flexbox characteristics such as `flex-direction: column/row` will decide what direction the elements in a given container are displayed.